# Is there any MOOCS on statistical analysis of Applied behavioral economics?

Tags: descriptive-statistics, statistical-learning

I couldn't find a single MOOCs on Applied behavioral economics and statistics, on how can we used statistical analysis in behavioral economics. If someone can point me in the right direction, it would be great

Comment: What does MOOCs stand for?

Comment: Can you elaborate how applied behavioral economics is different from applied econometrics?

Comment: @Andy: MOOC is [Massive Open Online Course](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Massive_open_online_course) such as Coursera and edX

Comment: @Dimitriy: I would have thought applied behavioural economics was more like [A/B testing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A/B_testing) combined with some psychological rationalisation of the results